# json; duplicate keys and filter based on value

Tags: json, jq

Trying to filter json based on `addrtype` and printing `addr` if `addrtype` is `ipv4` and `vendor` if `addrtype` is `mac`.

So far I have `'"\(.addr) \(.addrtype) \(.vendor)"'` which results in:

```
"192.168.1.235 ipv4 null"
"18:B4:30:8D:AE:BA mac Nest Labs"
"192.168.1.236 ipv4 null"
"18:B4:30:8D:B6:18 mac Nest Labs"
"192.168.1.238 ipv4 null"
"0C:EA:C9:AF:4F:72 mac null"
"192.168.1.254 ipv4 null"
"0C:EA:C9:AF:4F:70 mac null"
```

Desired Result:

```
192.168.1.235 - Nest Labs
192.168.1.236 - Nest Labs
192.168.1.238 - 
192.168.1.254 -
```

Data:

```
[
  {
    "addr": "192.168.1.235",
    "addrtype": "ipv4"
  },
  {
    "addr": "18:B4:30:8D:AE:BA",
    "addrtype": "mac",
    "vendor": "Nest Labs"
  }
]
[
  {
    "addr": "192.168.1.236",
    "addrtype": "ipv4"
  },
  {
    "addr": "18:B4:30:8D:B6:18",
    "addrtype": "mac",
    "vendor": "Nest Labs"
  }
]
[
  {
    "addr": "192.168.1.238",
    "addrtype": "ipv4"
  },
  {
    "addr": "0C:EA:C9:AF:4F:72",
    "addrtype": "mac"
  }
]
[
  {
    "addr": "192.168.1.254",
    "addrtype": "ipv4"
  },
  {
    "addr": "0C:EA:C9:AF:4F:70",
    "addrtype": "mac"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your stated requirements don't match the stated expectation in relation to the given data.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired result:

```
jq -sr '.[] | "\(.[0].addr) - \(.[1].vendor//"")"' file
```